# Rewriting code for GPU using GLSL

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es

I have some code which currently runs on the CPU and is causing lagging issue for my OpenGL ES application. The code calculates the deforms of a mesh. Im having trouble understanding how I could get this code to run on the GPU to imrpove performance.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++)
    {
        // Update the positions
        dPositions[(i*3+0)] += [[pMorphs objectAtIndex:(i*3+0)] floatValue] * weight;
        dPositions[(i*3+1)] += [[pMorphs objectAtIndex:(i*3+1)] floatValue] * weight;
        dPositions[(i*3+2)] += [[pMorphs objectAtIndex:(i*3+2)] floatValue] * weight;

    // Update the normals
        dNormals[(i*3+0)] += [[nMorphs objectAtIndex:(i*3+0)] floatValue] * weight;
        dNormals[(i*3+1)] += [[nMorphs objectAtIndex:(i*3+1)] floatValue] * weight;
        dNormals[(i*3+2)] += [[nMorphs objectAtIndex:(i*3+2)] floatValue] * weight;

    }
```

Am I right in thinking to use GLSL I will need to create 3 uniforms using glUniform4fv to upload the pMorphs, nMorphs and weight values? How can I then return this value after the calculation and assign it to dPositions and dNormals?

Time Profile
[image: TimeProfile]

Comment: I can imagine that you also could get an big performance boost if you use arrays and floats directly instead of NSArray and NSNumber. Especially the floatvalue call costs you a bunch of time.

Comment: The problem is I store the arrays pMorphs and nMorphs in a NSDictionary and then retrieve them before the for-loop using initWithArray which I think costs a lot of time

Comment: Did you profile your code? Would be great to know precisely what is taking so long.

Comment: I have included the timrprofiel